# How do I properly place Bootstrap indicators in the upper right corner?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I would like to have my indicators in the upper right corner, as on the picture below [image]
The way that I did it, was to give the indicators a percentage height and width - but with this method I cant press/use my carousel-control on the right, because my indicators somehow covers it up... 
the example of the issue is on the following website: http://haagmedia.dk/klf/

This is the only styling I made on the indicators so far

```
.carousel-indicators {
    text-align: right;
    width: 76%;
    height: 89%;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

I hope you can help me, with this issue, so I can get the indicators in the upper right corner, without affecting the possibility to change slide, on the right :)

Comment: You're using a `height` of 89%.  Set that to a fixed height and you should avoid the overlap issue that is preventing you from accessing the left / right controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your height of 89% overlaps the control. if you use a fixed height and a fixed position, everything should work.

```
.carousel-indicators {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 76%;
    height: 20px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

adjust the fixed position values with percentages could be a good idea...

Comment: The only issue now, is that the fixed positioning, is giving me trouble with my responsive design, because the indicators centers in mobile-device-size. Which I guess i a part of the reason I used to percentage to start of with :) any clue to what I can do, so they stay in position when I shrink the window? sorry for lame questions, kind a new to Bootstrap :)

Comment: you could use standard css media queries and in case the width of the viewport is smaller than some value, you can adjust the values or use complete other positioning.